# join different tables and display match records on a row with mysql

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm currently working on two tables which require a type of a join. first table is called `profile` table and the other is called `matches` table

Profile Table

```
+------------+------+--------+
|  ID | Name |  Bal   |
+------------+------+--------+
|1    |Daniel|  2000  |
+------------+------+--------+
|2    |Frank |  2000  |
+------------+------+--------+ 
|3    |Sarah |  2001  |
+------------+------+--------+
```

Matching Table

```
+------------+------+--------+
|  ID | User_ID |  Match_ID|
+------------+------+--------+
|1    |  1      |  2  |
+------------+------+--------+
|2    |1        |  3  |
+------------+------+--------+ 
|3    |3        |  1  |
+------------+------+--------+
```

Above are sample tables, now how do i write a query that will bring out both names of the of the User_ID and Match_ID field both on one row

Expected Results after query

```
+------------+------+--------+
|  ID | Name    | Match Name|
+------------+------+--------+
|1    |  Daniel |  Frank  |
+------------+------+--------+
|2    |Daniel   |  Sarah  |
+------------+------+--------+ 
|3    |Sarah    |  Daniel  |
+------------+------+--------+
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You simply use two joins:

```
select m.*, pu.name, pm.name as match_name
from matching m left join
     profiles pu
     on m.user_id = pu.id left join
     profiles pm
     on m.match_id = pm.id;
```

Note that this uses `left join`.  This ensures that all rows in `matching` will be in the result set, even if one of the columns does not have a value.

Answer (score 0):

```
Select p.id,p.name,p2.name match_name 
from profile p 
left join matches m on m.user_id=p.id
left join profile p2 on m.match_id=p2.id
```